# django pass parameters from form to view

Tags: python, django

I have a form that accepts a single date, or a date range. The date is then passed to a subsequent view that queries the DB and produces a result. I've managed to pass the single date via the URL 
 but I have yet to find a means to pass the date range from the form to the subsequent view where the query is run. 
( Note: I understand that the indentation of the form presented below is off. For some this is my first post and I'm not yet wise to all the subtleties of stack overflow)

```
class Date_rangeFRM(forms.Form):
Single_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
Date_start = forms.DateField(required=False)
Date_end = forms.DateField(required=False) 



def date_range(request):
context = RequestContext(request)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Date_rangeFRM(request.POST)
    print "valid", form.is_valid()
    print "form", str(form)
    if form.is_valid():
            #print "form", str(form)
        Single_date = form.cleaned_data['Single_date']
        Date_start = form.cleaned_data['Date_start']
        Date_end = form.cleaned_data['Date_end']


        if Single_date != "":
            #print "redirecting to Dav View:", '/counter/%02d-%02d-%02d/Day_view/' %(Single_date.year,Single_date.month,Single_date.day)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/counter/%02d-%02d-%02d/Day_view/' %(Single_date.year,Single_date.month,Single_date.day))



        else:
            #****passing Magic ********

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/counter/History_View/')
    else: 
        print form.errors

else:
    form = Date_rangeFRM()

return render_to_response('counter/historyFRM.html', {'form':form}, context)





def History_View(request):
context = RequestContext(request)

    #****** Receiving magic******** 

date_start = form.cleaned_data['date_start']
date_end = form.cleaned_data['date_end']
context['meal_list'] = meal_list
context['comp_list'] = comp_list
context['day_list']  = day_list             

dt_range = []  

day_list = RecordedDays.objects.filter(profile= request.user.userprofile, 
Date__gte = date_start, Date__lte = date_end     )

for day in day_list:
    dt_range.append(day.Date)

    meal_list = MealType.objects.filter(
    newDay__profile = request.user.userprofile, 
    newDay__Date__gte = date_start, newDay__Date__lte = date_end     )
                #newDay__Date= date( int(year),  int(month), int(day) ) )
    for meal in meal_list:
        dt_range.append([ meal.get_mealNum_display(), meal.Mealtotal()  ])
        comp_list =Ingredient.objects.filter(numMeal = meal)


        for comp in comp_list:
            dt_range[-1].append([comp.component, comp.comp_total()] )  




return render_to_response('counter/history_view.html', context
```

Also I'm not entirely sure I'm using the __lte,  __gte feature correctly. If you could please inspect it. Much appreciated. 
Thanks One and all for your Help.

Comment: what is the url for `'/counter/History_View/'` ??

Comment: That is the url for the subsequent view that will process the date range query.